# Calling upon a constructor with an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to create a program that takes user input for a student's name and GPA and inputs the information into a single arraylist. Pretty much, I'm trying to create an `ArrayList` that stores both a float and a string variable and is storing user input. I'm trying to use a constructor to accomplish this task, but I'm having trouble getting my code to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class BestStudent {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    static String name;
    static float gpa;

    private class Student {
    public Student (String n, float g){
        name = n;
        gpa = g;
    }
    }

    public static void findValidictorian(){
        ArrayList<Student> validictorian = new ArrayList<Student>();
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Please enter student name: ");
                name.add(scanner.next());
                System.out.println("Please enter your student's cumulative GPA: ");
                gpa.add(scanner.nextFloat());

                System.out.println("do you want to add another student yes/no?");
                String answer = scanner.next();

                if (answer.toLowerCase().equals("no")){
                    break;
                }


            }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findValidictorian();
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on both of my add methods for my ArrayList, and I can't for the life of my figure out why.

Comment: Did you perhaps intend to create a new BestStudent object, set its fields with what you read from the scanner, ***then*** add it to the list?

Comment: You should store the `name` and `gpa` fields within the inner class itself, not in the outer class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validictorian` is an `ArrayList`, but you're trying to add to `gpa` and `name`, which are *not* `ArrayList`s, and you never add to `validictorian`.  I think what you want is more like

```
name = scanner.next();
...
gpa = scanner.nextFloat();
validictorian.add(new Student(name, gpa));
```

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong. I just learned Arraylists today, and boy do I feel stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `gpa` are not array lists, you can't `add` elements to them. The only `ArrayList` in sight is called `validictorian` (sic.) and anyway, you can't add elements of different types to an `ArrayList` (well, you *could* add them if the `ArrayList` is parameterized to use type `Object`, but that's a bad practice.)

Notice that `validictorian` is supposed to contain objects of type `Student`. What you meant to do all along was this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter student name: ");
String aName = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Please enter your student's cumulative GPA: ");
float aGpa = scanner.nextFloat();
validictorian.add(new Student(aName, aGpa));
```